# Error Compiling in quartus

Tags: vhdl

I keep receiving an error while compiling my code below in quartus even though it does in the code below:

Error (12002): Port "qsys_dram_clk" does not exist in macrofunction "u0"

library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity flappyroscoe is

```
port(
CLOCK_50                 : IN    STD_LOGIC                     := 'X';             
CLOCK_27                 : IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 downto 0);                                  
AUD_XCK                  : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
I2C_SDAT                 : INOUT STD_LOGIC                     := 'X';             
I2C_SCLK                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
AUD_ADCDAT               : IN    STD_LOGIC                     := 'X';             
AUD_ADCLRCK              : IN    STD_LOGIC                     := 'X';             
AUD_BCLK                 : IN    STD_LOGIC                     := 'X';             
DRAM_ADDR                : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);                    
DRAM_BA_1                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;  
DRAM_BA_0                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC; 
DRAM_CAS_N               : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
DRAM_CKE                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
DRAM_CS_N                : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
DRAM_DQ                  : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => 
DRAM_UDQM                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC; 
DRAM_LDQM                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
DRAM_RAS_N               : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
DRAM_WE_N                : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
VGA_HS                   : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                           VGA_VS                   : OUT   STD_LOGIC;                                        
VGA_R                    : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);                     
VGA_G                    : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);                     
VGA_B                    : OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);                     
DRAM_CLK                : OUT   STD_LOGIC  
);
end entity;

architecture behavior of flappyroscoe is 

component flappy_system is

 port (

clk_clk: in    std_logic:= 'X';           
up_clocks_0_clk_in_secondary_clk: IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 downto 0);             
up_clocks_0_audio_clk_clk: out   std_logic;                                        
audio_and_video_config_0_external_interface_SDAT : inout std_logic:= 'X';            
audio_and_video_config_0_external_interface_SCLK : out   std_logic;                                        
audio_0_external_interface_ADCDAT : in    std_logic:= 'X';            
audio_0_external_interface_ADCLRCK : in    std_logic:= 'X';             
audio_0_external_interface_BCLK: in    std_logic:= 'X';             
qsys_dram_addr : out   std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);                    
qsys_dram_ba : out   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);                    
qsys_dram_cas_n : out   std_logic;                                       
qsys_dram_cke: out   std_logic;                                        
qsys_dram_cs_n: out   std_logic;                                        
qsys_dram_dq : inout std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => 'X'); 
qsys_dram_dqm  : out   std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);                     
qsys_dram_ras_n: out   std_logic;                                        
qsys_dram_we_n: out   std_logic;                                        
qsys_vga_HS: out   std_logic;                                        
qsys_vga_VS: out   std_logic;                                       
qsys_vga_R: out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);                    
qsys_vga_G: out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);                    
qsys_vga_B: out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);                   
qsys_dram_clk: out   std_logic  

        );

end component flappy_system;

signal dqm_sig,ba_sig: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal n: std_logic;

begin
DRAM_BA_1 <= ba_sig(1);
DRAM_BA_0 <= ba_sig(0);
DRAM_UDQM <= dqm_sig(1);
DRAM_LDQM <= dqm_sig(0);    

u0 : component flappy_system

port map (

clk_clk                                          => CLOCK_50,                                          
up_clocks_0_clk_in_secondary_clk                 => CLOCK_27,                 
up_clocks_0_audio_clk_clk                        => AUD_XCK,                        
audio_and_video_config_0_external_interface_SDAT => I2C_SDAT, 
audio_and_video_config_0_external_interface_SCLK => I2C_SCLK, 
audio_0_external_interface_ADCDAT                => AUD_ADCDAT,                
audio_0_external_interface_ADCLRCK               => AUD_ADCLRCK,               
audio_0_external_interface_BCLK                  => AUD_BCLK,                 
qsys_dram_addr                                   => dram_addr,                                   
qsys_dram_ba                                     => ba_sig,                                   
qsys_dram_cas_n                                  => dram_cas_n,                               
qsys_dram_cke                                    => dram_cke,                                 
qsys_dram_cs_n                                   => dram_cs_n,                                   
qsys_dram_dq                                     => dram_dq,                                    
qsys_dram_dqm                                    => dqm_sig,                                   
qsys_dram_ras_n                                  => dram_ras_n,                                 
qsys_dram_we_n                                   => dram_we_n,                                  
qsys_vga_HS                                      => vga_HS,                                     
qsys_vga_VS                                      => vga_VS,                                     
qsys_vga_R                                       => vga_R,                                     
qsys_vga_G                                       => vga_G,                                     
qsys_vga_B                                       => vga_B,                                     
qsys_dram_clk                                    => DRAM_CLK                                
 );

end architecture;
```

Comment: Double check the entity declaration for that component.

Comment: The VGA_VS got copied wrong in the post, however in quartus i have it correct. The qsys_dram_clk is pointing to DRAM_CLK as shown in the entity and it still shows the same error

Comment: No, look at `entity flappysystem`, it's in some other file somewhere that you haven't posted.

Comment: Sorry , are you referring to the entity flappyroscoe declaration above the port ?